# Extendscript: How to check whether text content overflows the containing rectangle

Tags: extendscript, photoshop-script, photoshop-cs5

I am using Extendscript for Photoshop CS5 to change the text of a text layer. Is there a way of checking whether the text fits e.g. by checking whether it overflows after changing the content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't found a way to do this directly. But I've used the following technique to determine the height I needed for a textbox (I wanted to keep the width constant) before.

- expand the textbox's height well beyond what is needed to accommodate the text inside it.
- duplicate the layer
- rasterize the duplicate
- measure the bounds of the rasterized layer.
- adjust the bounds of the original text layer as needed
- delete the rasterized duplicate

Totally roundabout - but it did work.

Comment: Thanks for the solution! If only there was a more direct means, but this will do for what I am doing right now.

Answer (score 4):

I created a solution that works perfectly fine :). Maybe someone else can use it as well. Let me know if it works for you too!

```
function scaleTextToFitBox(textLayer) {     
    var fitInsideBoxDimensions = getLayerDimensions(textLayer);

    while(fitInsideBoxDimensions.height < getRealTextLayerDimensions(textLayer).height) {
        var fontSize = parseInt(textLayer.textItem.size);
        textLayer.textItem.size = new UnitValue(fontSize * 0.95, "px");
    }
}

function getRealTextLayerDimensions(textLayer) {
    var textLayerCopy = textLayer.duplicate(activeDocument, ElementPlacement.INSIDE);

    textLayerCopy.textItem.height = activeDocument.height;
    textLayerCopy.rasterize(RasterizeType.TEXTCONTENTS);

    var dimensions = getLayerDimensions(textLayerCopy);
    textLayerCopy.remove();

    return dimensions;
}

function getLayerDimensions(layer) {
    return { 
        width: layer.bounds[2] - layer.bounds[0],
        height: layer.bounds[3] - layer.bounds[1]
    };
}
```

**How to use / Explanation**

1. Create a text layer that has a defined width and height.
2. You can change the text layers contents and then call `scaleTextToFitBox(textLayer);`

**The function will change the text/font size until the text fits inside the box (so that no text is invisible)!**

The script decreases the font size by 5% (* 0.95) each step until the texts fits inside the box. You can change the multiplier to achieve a more precise result or to increase performance.

Comment: This solution still works even in Adobe Photoshop 2020.